# Radiobutton group, change event?

Tags: php, events, cakephp, radio-button

I have a group of radiobuttons generated by cakephp.

```
<input type="radio" name="data[hexInput]" id="HexInput1" value="h1">
<input type="radio" name="data[hexInput]" id="HexInput2" value="h2">
<input type="radio" name="data[hexInput]" id="HexInput3" value="h3">
```

Is there some way to check if one of the radiobuttons in the group was checked? By a change event or something?

I know how to do this with a specific button but not with the group. For a specific button i use this Js helper:

```
$this->Js->get('HexInput2')->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
            'controller' => 'designer',
            'action' => 'test',
                ), array(
            'update' => '#resultDiv',
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                'isForm' => false,
                'inline' => true
            )) 
       ))
);
```

Comment: Try to replace change to click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an onclick for each radio button. You could do something like this:

```
function update(val) {
    alert("Radio button changed to " + val);
}
```

Then just tie it to each of the inputs like this:

```
<input onclick="update(this.value);" type="radio" name="data[hexInput]" id="HexInput1" value="h1">
<input onclick="update(this.value);" type="radio" name="data[hexInput]" id="HexInput2" value="h2">
<input onclick="update(this.value);" type="radio" name="data[hexInput]" id="HexInput3" value="h3">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/FindingtheSelectedButtoninaRadioGroup.htm